# Set inside a vector inside a vector

Tags: c++, vector, set

I am trying to implement a matrix box and for that to work I **have** to use a set inside a vector inside another vector.

```
  vector<vector<set<int> > > matrix;
```

however I have to set the size of my vectors in my constructor so I tried this

```
matrix(3,vector<set<int> >(4));
```

however It gave me an error **`type 'vector<vector<set<int> > >' does not provide a call operator`**.
Can someone explain why is this happening?

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b480f79493c9c60d)!

Comment: @user0042 even if i do what you did I get this error " error: expected parameter declarator
  vector<vector<set<int> > > matrix(3,vector<set<int> >(4));"

Comment: What's your compiler version, how do you call it from the command line?

Comment: @user0042 4.2.1 and g++ -std=c++11 -g -o sample sample.cpp

Comment: That's a pretty old version. Can't you get a more recent one?

Comment: @user0042 still the same error type 'vector > >' does not provide a call operator

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] in your question please. Add all relevant information.

Comment: @user0042 you wrote your version differently than what is posted in the question.

Comment: the question is **minimal** and **complete** , what else can I add if this is the only code in my program?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani OK, but [that's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66eb3ea4ea86cb43) completely silly, and isn't a _"constructor call"_.

Comment: Are you sure you have the version info right? It looks like gcc 4.2.1 [doesn’t accept](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-std_003d-630) `-std=c++11` or even `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
matrix(3,vector<set<int> >(4));
```

doesn't call the constructor, but tries to call an overloaded call operator (`operator()()`) of `std::vector`, which doesn't provide one.

To call the constructor write

```
vector<vector<set<int> > > matrix(3,vector<set<int> >(4));
```

Comment: Any idea why everything works fine if i change set<int> to int?